# Why implicit conversion is occurring in "if expression" although it should be explicit conversion

Tags: c++11, type-conversion, explicit

This code is not supposed to compile , so why it is ? 
what is the principle of the context in if expression ?

```
class B {  
public:  
    B() {}  
    explicit operator bool () {}  
};  



int main (){  
    B Bp;  
  //bool check = Bp // error
    if (Bp){   //o.k
        return 1;  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's is supposed to compile, that's a context that is considered "explicit".

Comment: You'll find relevant posts by searching for "[c++] contextually converted bool" (without the quotes)

Comment: What are the contexts that are considered "explicit" where I can find some information about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code very much is supposed to compile. The standard expended a very great deal of effort to *ensure* that it does.

There are a number of places where an expression is "contextually converted to bool" In those places, `explicit` bool conversions will be called if they're available. One of those contextual conversions is the `if` expression, as in your case.

This language allows `explicit operator bool` types to still be used for conditional checking `if(expr)`, but you can't other things without an explicit conversion. You can't pass it to a function that takes a `bool`; you can't return it from a function that returns `bool`, and so forth.

All of the contextual conversions are explicit expressions in language features. So `explicit operator bool` protects you from implicit user-defined conversions, while still allowing language-defined conversions to happen.